# How to retrieve WordPress login URL after changing it (hiding Backend) with ithemes-security plugin

Tags: wordpress

I used the iThemes-securitiy plugin to change the wp-admin url, and login page.

So my previous admin page (`https://www.example.com/wp-admin`) now gives an HTTP 404 error (File Not Found). Unfortunately, I do not remember what I have set the admin console URL to. How can I figure this out? I have access to the database and to the file system via SSH.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**step 1: de-activate iThemes security plugin**

As you cannot login to the wp-admin console, you will need ssh or ftp access to achieve this. Rename the plugin folder (on earlier installations, this folder is called 'better-wp-security')

```
$ cd /www/wp-content/plugins
$ mv better-wp-security better-wp-security-disabled
```

(or: do a rename using your ftp client)

**step 2: access wp-admin**

You can now access wp-admin again. Login, and keep yourself logged in. (leave browser open on wp-admin console)

**step 3: re-activate iThemes security plugin**

- Rename the plugin folder back to its original name
- Using wp-admin, activate the plugin again (as it was renamed, is was automatically de-activated in step 2)
- note that your previous setting is kept, so from now, accessing https://www.example.com/wp-admin directly is disabled again. But as you have your session open (from step 2), you can modify settings

**step 4: set a known login slug**

In wp admin, go to:

security > advanced (selector at the top) > Hide Backend > configure settings (button)

You can review and change your login slug.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. So I need to do a search in the plugin directory?

Comment: step 1 you need to enter in admin panel but you cant, step 2 so to did it you need FTP, go to yourwebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/... rename folder iThemes-securitiy or just move somewere on level up ... or rename. step 3 You will deactivate plugin so the url back in normal position,  step 4 then go yourwebsite.com/wp-admin.  step 5 install again or move back iThemes-securitiy folder. step 6 carefull after again start plugin do not leave wp-admin, find area ~login slug -- field.  and its Done .

Comment: you can disable the ithemes sec plugin by placing in `wp-config.php` `define('ITSEC_DISABLE_MODULES', true);` [ithemeshelp](https://ithemeshelp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201937754-I-Forgot-My-Hide-Backend-URL)

Comment: If You have access to wp-cli: to "deactivate" ```wp plugin deactivate better-wp-security```  and to activate: ```wp plugin activate better-wp-security```

Answer (score 9):

In the actual version of the plugin you need to check `wp_options` table and look to row with `option_name` = `itsec-storage`, here inside `option_value` will be json data, and inside this json data you can find `hide-backend` array where `slug` variable this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To recover your custom wp-admin search a code similar to the following in the `.htaccess` file in your WordPress root installation:

```
# Enable the hide backend feature - Security > Settings > Hide Login Area > Hide Backend
RewriteRule ^(/)?your-new-login/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?wp-register-php/?$ /wplogin?action=register [QSA,L]
# END iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the database, the wp_options table has an "itsec_hide_backend" option.  One value (slug) is your renamed wp-admin.

Answer (score 1):

And if not WP CLI, if you have access to the hosting backend / SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` where option_name = "itsec-storage";
```

look for 'slug' in the value array

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I have fixed this by restoring the site from backup.

iThemes security does not seem to store this on the file system (i.e. `.htaccess`). Restoring the file system from backup wat not enough.
The setting is kept somewhere in the database as well (I got back in once the database was restored).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the existing answers worked for me as well. I went to the directory 
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security and inside the "better-wp-security" folder there was a file named "better-wp-security.php". I simply renamed it "disabled-better-wp-security" and I was able to login through the default WordPress login URL.

P.S. This was on version 7.1.0 of the iThemes plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this using a different trick I learned from an awesome colleague of mine. You can force wordpress to use a specific url by adding two lines to the wp-login.php. Open this file and look for this line that should already be present in the wp-login file:

> require( dirname(**FILE**) . '/wp-load.php' );

Immediately after it enter the next two lines:

```
update_option('siteurl', 'https://exampledomain.com/wp-admin' );
update_option('home', 'https://exampledomain.com/wp-admin' );
```

(Where "exampledomain.com" obviously should be replaced by your own domain name)
Now the wordpress dashboard should be at exampledomain.com/wp-admin again.

Sometimes this isn't enough though and you still have to disable the .htaccess file (and sometimes the security plugin(s) responsible as well) by renaming them in any of the ways that are allready mentioned in the previous answers.

Edit: this is a temporary hack. Don't forget to remove these lines after you made the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, the hidden URL is stored in the `slug` entry of the `itsec-storage` row in the database's wp_options table.

If you have WP CLI installed, you can retrieve the slug in a one liner command:

`wp option get itsec-storage | grep "'slug'"`